# How to get a script executed when the user confirms an action?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert2

I'm doing a delete of records with the SweetAlert library and I want that when the user clicks the delete button a warning message appears. When I press the delete button the message appears and then the delete is executed, I want to avoid that, I just want it to be executed when the user confirms.

I made this action with Jquery and Ajax::

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function () {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Chat?',
            text: "You will not be able to recover the data!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
        }).then(function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Removed!',
                    'A chat was deleted.',
                    'success'
                ).then(function () {

                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteChat", "Chat")',
                                data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings(".td-id").text().trim() },
                                success: function (rpta) {

                                },
                                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                                }
                           });

                    });
            } else {

            }
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function() {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Chat?',
            text: "You will not be able to recover the data!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
        }).then((isConfirm) => {
            if (isConfirm.value) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteChat", "Chat")',
                    data: {
                        id: $(this).parent().siblings(".td-id").text().trim()
                    },
                    success: function(rpta) {

                    },
                    error: function(req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });

            } else {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello @FarhaniWalid, I did not succeed with your answer, I checked the documentation of SweetAlert and I did not succeed either.

Comment: The alert appears and then my record is deleted. It does not let me show the alert so the user can read the message.

Comment: Hi there, so could you please explain to me step by step what do you want to do ?